# Iteration through an array reads n-1 elements from array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to read an array starting from the 5th element and store the subsequent elements. My array has length 100, so when i start from 5 in my loop it outputs 99. I tried printing the results before and after the loop, before the loop the output is 100 and after the loop the output is 99.

```
randnums = np.random.randint(1,150, 100) # generating an array
print(len(randnums)) # checking the length before the loop
for i in range(5, randnums.size): # iteration
    test = randnums[:i] # storing the values

print((test.size)) # checking the output: will give 99
```

Why cannot i store the 100th element?

Comment: `//` is floor division operator

Comment: The loop is pointless here

Comment: This is a reproducible example, i have a function that i need to call n times using the values in test

Comment: Agreed that it's reproducible. It's just not minimal. I posted an answer that shows that the error is immediately apparent when you try to minimize it. Welcome to zero based indexing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at your loop. It overwrites `test` at every iteration, so you only really need to look the last value of `i`.

You're using a range from `5` inclusive, to `randnums.size == 100` (exclusive). Ranges are exclusive on the upper bound. The last element of the range is `99`. You can check this by printing it directly (ranges are sequences):

```
>>> print(range(5, randnums.size)[-1])
99
```

Your code is therefore equivalent to

```
test = randnums[:99]
print(test.size)
```

The result should not be unexpected at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are actually 0 to 99. Zero is a real number and has a place as the first location in an array. Therefore you set up 0-99 no9t 1-100.

Answer (score -1):

That is because of the colon operator. [:n] doesn't include n-th element.

You can see [here](https://youtu.be/tKTZoB2Vjuk?t=41m40s) (Around 40:00) how it works

So, it you want to get an array with same size from the original one

```py
randnums = np.random.randint(1,150, 100) # generating an array
print(len(randnums)) # checking the length before the loop
for i in range(5, randnums.size + 1): # iteration
    test = randnums[:i] # storing the values

print((test.size)) # checking the output: will give 99
```

Comment: What do you mean [:n] does not include the n-th element?

Comment: 0th, 1st, 2nd, ...(n-1)st not n-th

Comment: @rckjns Try randnums.size+1 in range